# XQuery: convert XML to RDF

Tags: xquery, basex

I am trying to convert XML to RDF(RDF/XML syntax) using XQuery. I think I encounter something I could not overcome...

test.xqy:

```
declare namespace rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#";
declare namespace owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#";
declare namespace xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#";
declare namespace rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#";

import module namespace functx="http://www.functx.com";

declare variable $srcDoc:="test.xml";
declare variable $defaultXMLNS:="http://www.test.com#";
declare variable $defaultXMLBase:=$defaultXMLNS;


declare function local:getQName($local as xs:string?)
as xs:QName?
{
  QName($defaultXMLNS, $local)
};

declare function local:namedIndividualConstructor($pnode as node()*)
as node()*
{
  element owl:NamedIndividual
  {
    (:to avoid repeated names, unique uuid is generated for each individuals:)
    attribute rdf:about {concat("#", random:uuid(), "_", $pnode/name())},
    element rdf:type {attribute rdf:resource {concat("#", $pnode/name())}},

    for $x in $pnode/*
    return element {local:getQName(concat($pnode/name(), "_", $x/name()))}
    {
      attribute rdf:resource {}
    }

  }
};

element rdf:RDF
{
  namespace {""} {$defaultXMLNS},
  attribute xml:base {$defaultXMLBase},
  element owl:Ontology
  {
    attribute rdf:about {$defaultXMLNS}
  },
  for $x in doc($srcDoc)//*
  return if($x[not(child::*)])
  then ()
  (:only generate namedIndividual for nodes having leaf nodes:)
  else local:namedIndividualConstructor($x)
}
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
  <name>French Toast aaa</name>
  <price>$5.95</price>
  <description>Our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
  <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
  <name>French Toast</name>
  <price>$4.50</price>
  <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
  <calories>600</calories>
</food>
<food>
  <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
  <price>$6.95</price>
  <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
  <calories>950</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

command line:

```
basex -o testxqyoutput.rdf test.xqy
```

testxqyoutput.rdf:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.test.com#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xml:base="http://www.test.com#">
  <owl:Ontology xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" rdf:about="http://www.test.com#"/>
  <owl:NamedIndividual xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" rdf:about="#82ab6f48-2faf-4782-840f-59e6e96403ef_breakfast_menu">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#breakfast_menu"/>
    <breakfast_menu_food rdf:resource=""/>
    <breakfast_menu_food rdf:resource=""/>
    <breakfast_menu_food rdf:resource=""/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:NamedIndividual xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" rdf:about="#04f02acc-da19-47a7-a69a-98cc958efbbd_food">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#food"/>
    <food_name rdf:resource=""/>
    <food_price rdf:resource=""/>
    <food_description rdf:resource=""/>
    <food_calories rdf:resource=""/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:NamedIndividual xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" rdf:about="#bfec0a13-ac56-4ac8-a9bb-0575b16e601a_food">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#food"/>
    <food_name rdf:resource=""/>
    <food_price rdf:resource=""/>
    <food_description rdf:resource=""/>
    <food_calories rdf:resource=""/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:NamedIndividual xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" rdf:about="#7f6411cb-3619-4b61-8b78-3b1e8ec99898_food">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#food"/>
    <food_name rdf:resource=""/>
    <food_price rdf:resource=""/>
    <food_description rdf:resource=""/>
    <food_calories rdf:resource=""/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I use `uuid` to avoid duplicate child element, so for different `<food>`, there is a different name. The output `testxqyoutput.rdf` may not look like a valid rdf file, I discarded some not related details of the source code.
The real problem is: I don't know how to assign the corresponding name to `rdf:resource`.

The first generated NamedIndividual should look like this:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" rdf:about="#82ab6f48-2faf-4782-840f-59e6e96403ef_breakfast_menu">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#breakfast_menu"/>
    <breakfast_menu_food rdf:resource="#04f02acc-da19-47a7-a69a-98cc958efbbd_food"/>
    <breakfast_menu_food rdf:resource="#bfec0a13-ac56-4ac8-a9bb-0575b16e601a_food"/>
    <breakfast_menu_food rdf:resource="#7f6411cb-3619-4b61-8b78-3b1e8ec99898_food"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<owl:NamedIndividual xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" rdf:about="#04f02acc-da19-47a7-a69a-98cc958efbbd_food">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#food"/>
        <food_name rdf:resource=""/>
        <food_price rdf:resource=""/>
        <food_description rdf:resource=""/>
        <food_calories rdf:resource=""/>
      </owl:NamedIndividual>
      <owl:NamedIndividual xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" rdf:about="#bfec0a13-ac56-4ac8-a9bb-0575b16e601a_food">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#food"/>
        <food_name rdf:resource=""/>
        <food_price rdf:resource=""/>
        <food_description rdf:resource=""/>
        <food_calories rdf:resource=""/>
      </owl:NamedIndividual>
      <owl:NamedIndividual xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" rdf:about="#7f6411cb-3619-4b61-8b78-3b1e8ec99898_food">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#food"/>
        <food_name rdf:resource=""/>
        <food_price rdf:resource=""/>
        <food_description rdf:resource=""/>
        <food_calories rdf:resource=""/>
      </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

How do I modify the code to achieve this valid output?
I think the real problem is: XQuery is functional programming language. And all NamedIndividuals are generated by a function. There is no way to share status between functions. And there is no concept `global variable` in XQuery...

Comment: What about storing the uuid into a variable above element constructors and using it simply twice? It seems you generate it directly in the constructor, which, or course, prevents it to be used more than once.

Comment: @HonzaHejzl Could you pls be more specific? Do you mean putting the pre-generated uuid in the for loop of rdf:RDF, or in the for loop in function namedIndividualConstructor? thx

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this could work. Besides, am I right the `attribute rdf:resource {}` in your code does nothing because it is empty?

```
declare function local:namedIndividualConstructor($pnode as node()*)
as node()*
{
  (:to avoid repeated names, unique uuid is generated for each individuals:)
  let $id := concat("#", random:uuid(), "_", $pnode/name())
  element owl:NamedIndividual
  {
    attribute rdf:about {$id},
    element rdf:type {attribute rdf:resource {concat("#", $pnode/name())}},

    for $x in $pnode/*
    return element {local:getQName(concat($pnode/name(), "_", $x/name()))}
    {
      attribute rdf:resource {$id}
    }

  }
};
```